# SQL Server 2005 query pivot over variable number of schedules

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am working on a routing system for a transportation type similar to a bus routing system like below.
I have a view that gives me the output. I need to pivot over schedules where the number of schedules can be of a variable quantity.

My query should result in the output given below in the image. I tried using Case Statements but I had problems with the number of rows returned.

Here are the scripts to generate the table and the data for reference:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ScheduleTest]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ScheduleTest](
[StationName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[ScheduleNumber] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[ArrivalTime] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[DepartureTime] [nvarchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
  

--Insert Scripts For Schedule A
Insert into ScheduleTest Values ('Chicago, IL, (Union Station)', 'ScheduleA', NULL, '02:45')
Insert into ScheduleTest Values ('Chicago, IL, (DownTown)', 'ScheduleA', '02:55', '03:00')
Insert into ScheduleTest Values ('Benton, MI, Harbor', 'ScheduleA', '08:00', NULL) --Benton in this case 
--is final destination so departure time is null

-- Insert Scripts for Schedule B (Another Which runs in the morning)
Insert into ScheduleTest Values ('Chicago, IL, (Union Station)', 'ScheduleB', NULL, '06:00')
Insert into ScheduleTest Values ('Chicago, IL, (DownTown)', 'ScheduleB', '06:10', '06:15')
Insert into ScheduleTest Values ('Benton, IL, Harbor', 'ScheduleB', '11:00', NULL)
```

I don't think I can use pivoting in Sql server 2005 since it needs some sort of aggregates to work on. I have nothing aggregate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it from a different source... This works and thanks to one who suggested this answer

IF OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb..#ScheduleTest') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #ScheduleTest
GO

IF OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #tmp
GO

CREATE TABLE #ScheduleTest(
        [StationName] nvarchar NULL,
        [ScheduleNumber] nvarchar NULL,
        [ArrivalTime] nvarchar NULL,
        [DepartureTime] nvarchar NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

--Insert Scripts For Schedule A
Insert into #ScheduleTest Values ('Chicago, IL, (Union Station)', 'ScheduleA', NULL, '02:45')
Insert into #ScheduleTest Values ('Chicago, IL, (DownTown)', 'ScheduleA', '02:55', '03:00')
Insert into #ScheduleTest Values ('Benton, IL, Harbor', 'ScheduleA', '08:00', NULL) --Benton in this case 
--is final destination so departure time is null

-- Insert Scripts for Schedule B (Another Which runs in the morning)
Insert into #ScheduleTest Values ('Chicago, IL, (Union Station)', 'ScheduleB', NULL, '06:00')
Insert into #ScheduleTest Values ('Chicago, IL, (DownTown)', 'ScheduleB', '06:10', '06:15')
Insert into #ScheduleTest Values ('Benton, IL, Harbor', 'ScheduleB', '11:00', NULL)

SELECT
        StationName, ScheduleNumber, ArrivalTime AS TimeOfEvent, 'Arrival' AS [Arrival/Departure]
INTO #tmp
FROM
        #ScheduleTest
WHERE
        ArrivalTime IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
        StationName, ScheduleNumber, DepartureTime  AS TimeOfEvent, 'Departure' AS [Arrival/Departure]
FROM
        #ScheduleTest
WHERE
        DepartureTime IS NOT NULL

-- Due to the aggregation requirement of pivot, Only one Schedule/Station combination is allowed.
-- This is the query for the core data.  Now, to dynamic this:
SELECT
        StationName,
        ScheduleA,
        ScheduleB,
        [Arrival/Departure]
FROM
        #tmp AS t
        PIVOT
                ( MAX(TimeOfEvent) FOR ScheduleNumber IN ( ScheduleA, ScheduleB)
                ) AS pvt

DECLARE @sql nVARCHAR(MAX),
                @ScheduleNumber VARCHAR(50),
                @PivotInList nVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT StationName, '
SET @PivotInList = ' IN ('

DECLARE ScheduleCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT DISTINCT ScheduleNumber FROM #tmp

OPEN ScheduleCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM ScheduleCursor INTO @ScheduleNumber

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + @ScheduleNumber + ', '
        SET @PivotInList = @PivotInList + ' ' + @ScheduleNumber + ','

```
    FETCH NEXT FROM ScheduleCursor INTO @ScheduleNumber
```

END

CLOSE ScheduleCursor
DEALLOCATE ScheduleCursor

SET @PivotInList = LEFT( @PivotInList, LEN( @PivotInList) - 1 /*Remove the extra comma-space*/) + ')'
PRINT @PivotInList

SET @sql = @sql + '[Arrival/Departure] FROM #tmp AS t PIVOT ( MAX( TimeOfEvent) FOR ScheduleNumber'
                                + @PivotInList + ') AS pvt'
PRINT @sql

EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql

---

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is very efficient, but you can give it a try:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT StationName, ScheduleNumber, ArrivalTime ScheduleTime, 'Arrival' [Arrival/Departure]
    FROM ScheduleTest 
    WHERE ArrivalTime IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT StationName, ScheduleNumber, DepartureTime, 'Departure'
    FROM ScheduleTest 
    WHERE DepartureTime IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT  StationName, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN ScheduleNumber = 'ScheduleA' THEN ScheduleTime ELSE NULL END) ScheduleA,
        MIN(CASE WHEN ScheduleNumber = 'ScheduleB' THEN ScheduleTime ELSE NULL END) ScheduleB,
        [Arrival/Departure]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY StationName, [Arrival/Departure]
```

Comment: hmm... worth a try.. I can check something on this to see if I can make my schedules dynamic. As I said before, number of schedules will vary and won't be fixed to one or two, it can be anything from 2-40 in a day